# Ruby undesired object is being added to array instead of correct object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Associations:

```
class Foo
  has_many :foo_subscribers
end

class FooSubscriber
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :foo_subscribers
  belongs_to :employee
end

class Employee
  has_one :user
end
```

The following code is adding a `User` object to the array, despite the explicit call to `User`'s `Employee`

```
#foo.rb

employees_to_notify = Array.new

foo_subscribers.each do |user|
  employees_to_notify << user.employee
end
```

All of the appropriate data is present for the test.  Through debugging, I can evaluate `user.employee` as an employee object right on the line where it's added to the array.

How is this possible?  I've tried various things like iterating over the array and converting any `User` objects to `Employees`.  That also failed.

Comment: What class are the objects in `foo_subscribers`?

Comment: @japed: Wow, that question helped me solve the problem.  I was being foolish trying to get `foo_subscriber.employee` rather than `foo_subscriber.user.employee`.

Comment: Then you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are iterating over foo_subscribers, but then naming them as users in the pipes? Are foo_subscribers users?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get foo_subscriber.employee rather than foo_subscriber.user.employee.  I was attempting to perform an operation on the wrong type.